# PHP preg replace for variable in iframe

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a widget for users to enter in the code for an iframe widget that is created on another site. There are a few variations of what the iframe code that is generated from the other site will contain, so I want to strip out everything except for the 6 digits that identify the widget, and then echo back the iframe code with the digits inserted.

I'm not sure why this isn't working … The code I have been using is here:

```
<?php

$widget_id = $vars['entity']->widget_id;

if ($widget_id) {

    $widget_id = preg_replace('<iframe src=(.*?)/widgets/(\d+)(.*?)</iframe>', '$2', $widget_id);

    echo '<iframe src="http://website.com/widgets/'.$widget_id.'/player_universal" width="300" height="250"></iframe>';

}

else {
    echo "Enter the widget short code";
}
```

Comment: preg isn't valid you need to delimit it "/my regex/" to allow for other modifiers ie "/[a-z]/i" case-insensitive AND escape the /'s http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$widget_id = preg_replace('/\<iframe src=(.*?)\/widgets\/(\d+)(.*?)\<\/iframe\>/', '$2', $widget_id);
```

notice the delimiters around the regular expression / reg-exp /
you can make it case-insensitive too by using i modifier  / reg-exp /i

you also need to escape all the special reg-exp characters too (see preg_quote() for a list)

See
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

p.s. / is not the only character you can use, I've seen @ and | too

Comment: Can be simplified though(.*? = .* and < and > are not metacharacters): `'/<iframe src=.*\/widgets\/(\d+).*<\/iframe>/'` (use $1).

Comment: @AnotherTest The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php and the delimiter needs to be escaped too which is /

Comment: @Waygood I guess they can occur in conditions, although you don't have any conditions. http://ideone.com/h3AjCn